# convergent sequence tends to single limit by triangle inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence

I am reading The Foundations of Mathematics by Stewart & Tall.  On pg 36 they discuss the fact that a convergent sequence can only tend to a single limit, otherwise it would imply the sequence converging in two places at once. I have no problem understanding this concept, however they then go on to demonstrate it mathematically by citing the triangle inequality and I am at a complete loss at understanding their application of the triangle inequality here.  I understand the triangle inequality as well, but I don't understand why they cite it or how it applies.  Can someone please explain and relieve my confusion?  thanks! From their text:

**Definition 2.9:** A sequence $(a_n)$ which tends to a limit *l* is called *convergent*.  If no limit exists, it is said to be divergent.
   A convergent sequence can tend to only one limit.  For suppose $a_n \rightarrow m$, where $l \neq m$. Take $\epsilon = \frac 12 |l-m|$. For large enough n,

$$|a_n - l| \lt \epsilon, |a_n - m| \lt \epsilon.$$

From the triangle inequality, $|l - m| \lt 2\epsilon = |l - m|$, which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

It's just that$$\begin{align*}|l-m|&=|l-a_n+a_n-m|\\&\leqslant|l-a_n|+|a_n-m|\text{ (triangle inequality)}\\&=|a_n-l|+|a_n-m|\\&<\epsilon+\epsilon\\&<2\epsilon.\end{align*}$$